# Is there a way for me to force the browser to fix invalid markup by rerendering a specific element on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, gecko

I have a situation where elements are changed on the fly through a specific component.
This component changes the innerHTML of these elements but doesn't actually rerender the element, but rather only its contents.
This leads to situations where the final DOM is different than it would be had it been on the page in the first place - this is a problem for me.

**An example of such a mix up is this:**
If we take the following markup:

```
<h1 id="foo">Hi there stranger!</h1>
```

And I add the following JS code:

```
document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = "Hi <h2>there</h2> stranger!";
```

We will result with the following markup:

```
<h1 id="foo">Hi <h2>there</h2> stranger!</h1>
```

It will be rendered same as seen above (with the H2 inside the H1), but if this markup were on the page in the first place it would get rendered as:

```
<h1>Hi</h1> <h2>there</h2> <h1>stranger!</h1>
```

Which obviously results in a different document.

**So, my question is this:**
How can I force the browser to rerender this markup?
I'd like to be able to refer to the above H1 and tell it to rerender in the **same way** it would have rendered in the first place.
How can I do this in all the major engines (Gecko, Webkit, IE)?

Comment: The H was only an example, there is an infinite number of markups that could be created by the component. It is dynamic and controlled by the end user. The H1 is only one example of variations in the rendering process - I've found differences in the way whitespace is treated, for example, and as users use white space to format their content 9using contentediatble) this is a major issue as the resulting markup is different than what the yintended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd call this "attempt to fix invalid markup", rather than "rerender". Anyways, you should assign html to a node that is higher in the hierarchy than the node in question. As a last resort, reloading the whole `<body>` should work:

```
 document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML
```

Another option would be to use `outerHTML`, that is:

```
document.getElementById('foo').outerHTML = "<h1>Hi <h2>there</h2> stranger!</h1>";
```

At least in FF, this appears to work as intended.

Comment: I thought of that as well, but it seems very costly. Especially for an element directly under the Body, as you mentioned.

Comment: But thanks for the comment on the title, I'll fix it, you're right. :)

Comment: wow, dynamite solution... all the dynamically attached event handlers go Buh-Bye...

Comment: Good point Jay (though the cynicism may have been a little strong ;))

Comment: Dude, that worked! Great, thanks.
It may cause me to loose events on the specific element, I need to check, but that I can deal with.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think a general process to do this would be to:

1. find the html node X
2. create the new content node and [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.insertBefore) the original node X
3. remove the node X

Comment: So you're saying, basically, create a clone of the original and remove the original?
I actually already tried this and it worked, but I don't want to do that as it can be expensive. I'd much rather force a rerender of the original if thats possible.

Comment: It's not really a clone since you're wanting to replace an h1 with an h2.

Comment: No, you misunderstood the situation. The H1 is already there and I don't know about it as the component can be used on any element on the DOM.
The user uses the component to add an H2 inside the H1.
The DOM is then rendered with the H2 inside the H1.
But if I store this DOM and serve it as part of the page next time the user visits the DOM breaks the H1 and H2 apart, because that markup is invalid.

Comment: Had it broken up the DOM in the first plac ethat would be fine, because then the user would see the result of his actions but as the browse r"lies" the first time around, the resulting DOM is invalid.
I'd like to force the browser to render the DOM correctly in  the first place.